# React native - how to refresh screen when message has been sent?

Tags: react-native

so currently I have 2 simulators open. Each simulator is logged in as a different user. When I enter the chat between these 2 users, messages are getting sent live in the socket which is perfect.

**My problem:**

Example: if user 1 is on the all messages screen and user 2 is inside the chat. And user 2 sends user 1 a message, user 1's screen does not automatically update with the new message, I need to either scroll to refresh or navigate from one page to the other.

How should I implement the when a new message is sent it gets shown to user 1?

Here is my code:

AllMessagesScreen.js

```js
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const[page,setPage]=useState(0);
    const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

    const loadPosts = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await messagesApi.getMessages();
    setLoading(false);

    if(refreshing) setRefreshing(false);

    if (!response.ok) return setError(true);

    setError(false);

    setPosts(response.data)
    };

    useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    loadPosts();
    });
    return unsubscribe;
    }, [navigation]);

    return(

    <FlatList
        data={posts}
        keyExtractor={(listing) => listing.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
          <MessagesList
          title={item.Post.title}
            subTitle={item.Messages[0].message}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.CHAT,{message:item,index})}
          />
        )}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={
          ListItemSeparator
        }
        refreshing={refreshing}
        onRefresh={() => {
          loadPosts()
        }}
      />
```

In other words, when a message is sent in the chat screen I want my allmessages screen to re-render, currently it is only getting render when I scroll to refresh or navigate to allmessages screen.

If you require any additional information please tell me, I will provide it immediately. Thank you

chat screen.js

```
function ChatScreen({route,navigation}) {  
const message = route.params.message;
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
const [text, setText] = useState('');
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [error, setError] = useState(false);
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
const { user } = useAuth();
const index = route.params.index;
const updateView = route.params.updateView;

useEffect(() => {
const newsocket =io.connect("IPADDRESS")
setMessages(message.Messages)

newsocket.on('connect', msg => {
    console.log(`user: ${user.id} has joined conversation ${message.id}`)
    setSocket(newsocket)
    newsocket.emit('subscribe', message.id);
 });

  newsocket.on("send_message", (msg) => {
    console.log("this is the chat messages:", msg);
    setMessages(messages => [msg, ...messages]);
  });
 
 return(()=>newsocket.close());

 }, []);
```

Comment: you need a web-socket (or something similar) connection open all the time to watch for new messages. Right now it looks like you are making an api call on screen focus and flatlist refresh only. If your backend can't do web-sockets, you need to keep hitting the messages get api in intervals, like every 10sec or so

Comment: @VaibhavVishal hi, i have socket implemented in my chat screen itself but not on the allmessages screen, i am supposed to create another connection just for getting the most recent message sent in the chat and add that to my allmessages screen? I have updated my code with my chatscreen code as well.

Comment: in our case we have a connection always watching list of group. And another watching messages of a group which opens/closes when you go in/out of a group to see all messages. To get the last messages of a group we have a field called lastMessage in each group so even when we are on group list the socket connection detects the change in group and you and show the last message. We also have fields like lastUpdated in group schema to help with things like these

Comment: @VaibhavVishal hi, i have a question in my all chats screen i created a connection thats always open but everytime i go back then to the all chats screen a new socket gets created. How do i keep the connection open always?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the groups schema like this:

```
{
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

and messages schema like this:

```
{
  id: string;
  groupId: string;
  text: string;
}
```

Now to recognise that a new message has been sent in a group you can add `lastMessage` in group schema, like this:

```
{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  lastMessage: Message;
}
```

This way your whenever a new message is sent, respective group will change, which will make the web-socket emit an event and you will get updated data.

In you db in `lastMessage` field you can have foreign key to message collection, but when sending the json to frontend send the whole message object.
Also you will have to update your function for message creation to update the group too with `lastMessage`.

If you have creation time in messages schema, having lastMessage in group will help with sorting them too, like showing group with latest message on top.

Comment: Currently, i have a conversation table and a messages table. when i send a message to a user a conversation is created between the 2 users and stored in my conversation tale at the same time the message sent gets stored in my messages table as well. in my conversation table i should add a field lastmessage which gets updated with the message id of the last message sent?

Comment: Yup, that's right. And add a web socket on conversation list too, just like you did on message list. But in message only new messages are getting created, in conversation an existing object might get updated too, so you will have to merge carefully and avoid duplicates

Comment: I am very confused on how to accomplish this at the moment, the alternative to this is to re render my allmessages screen every 10s?

Comment: Yup call `loadPosts` inside a setinterval. Something like this: `setInterval(loadPosts, 10000)` needs to go inside an useEffect

Comment: but obviously you recommend the socket correct?

Comment: Yes, of course, that's the better solution

Comment: let give it a try, i think i got the part to do with the database but not the socket part

Comment: Hi, i managed to store the lastMessage id inside my conversation table next to each corresponding conversation. What is the next step?

Comment: send the last message with conversation. then use a socket connection for conversation list too, like you did for message list

Comment: Do you mind helping with that, i kept trying but not working for some reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227192/discussion-between-vaibhav-vishal-and-kd12345).

Comment: Hi, a quick question if i use setInterval will this cause problems in my app?

Comment: A bit, not much

Comment: but it will cost alot if i host my app on AWS, right? since i will be hitting the api every 10s.

Comment: Yeah, if number of users increase, there will be too many API calls

Comment: how do i listen to the same event on 2 different screens in react native? i need to listen the same event on my chatscreen to render live messaging if both users are inside chat and on my allmessages screen to render the last message to the user not inside the chat.